# Why $ (\mathop{tr} B)^2 =\sum_{i,j} b_{ii} b_{jj}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

Given a symmetric matrix $B$ how we compute
$$(\mathop{tr}B)^2 =\sum_{i,j} b_{ii} b_{jj}.$$ Could you please someone cast some light?

Comment: Do you mean (trace of B) squared or trace of (B squared)? Your notation ambiguous.

Comment: Looks like you have a computable formula, no?

Comment: @coffeemath I have  (trace of B) squared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really just the fact that
$$(\sum_i a_i)^2 = (\sum_i a_i)(\sum_j a_j) = \sum_{i,j} a_i a_j$$

Comment: I didn't see that coming. It bothers me with as the not quadratic terms are not obvious at first sight. However, doing a simple example seems fine.